# dynamic dropdown is not working in php, data is not fetching from the database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

[image][image][image]I want to make a dropdown and values should be selected from the database. But in my case values are not shown in the dropdown.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F6O9.png
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors?

Also here's the way I usually do this kind of thing

[image: I usually do it like this]

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM parent_category";
$results=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
?>
<option.....<?php echo $row['parent_id']; ?>
<?php
}
//php continues
?>
```

Comment: No..this method is not worked for me. I'm not getting any err but  dropdown list is not visible. is there any other method ?

Comment: I just tested it and works just fine for me,. Does the sql return anything at all? because it could be something with your connection. Your table name is parent_category and fields are parent_id and parent_name? right

Comment: yes //table name is parent_category and fields are parent_id  and parent_name...chk my  database pic

Comment: what does the $results contain after query? Did you try $dump = mysqli_fetch_all($results) and dumping it (var_dump($dump);)